# Переопределение метода clone для массива

Tags: java, переопределение, clone

Вопрос, вот кусок кода, подскажите пожалуйста, как можно сделать что-бы метод clone вызывался и клонировал объект? ) Интересует именно вариант с переопределением метода класса Object. Потому как реализовать свой метод не проблема.

```
public static class AsciiCharSequence implements CharSequence{
    private final byte[] ascArr;

    public AsciiCharSequence(byte[] ascArr){
        this.ascArr = ascArr.clone();
    }

    @Override
    public byte[] clone() {
        byte[] cloneAscArr = new byte[ascArr.length];
        int index = 0;
        for (byte elem : ascArr){
           cloneAscArr[index] = elem;
           index++;
        }
        return cloneAscArr;
    }
```

Без переопределения я смог сделать так ( но хотелось бы понять, есть ли возможность переопределить) :

```
public AsciiCharSequence(byte[] ascArr){
    this.ascArr = clone(ascArr);
}

public byte[] clone(byte[] inputArray) {
    byte[] cloneAscArr = new byte[inputArray.length];
    int index = 0;
    for (byte elem : inputArray){
       cloneAscArr[index] = elem;
       index++;
    }
    return cloneAscArr;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Во-первых метод `clone()` имеет модификатор доступа `protected`, во-вторых, возвращает `Object`. Если хотите полностью переопределить и реализовать свою логику, тогда переопределяйте так:

```
@Override
protected Object clone() throws CloneNotSupportedException {
    // ваш код
}
```

Если вы пишите это:

```
public byte[] clone(byte[] inputArray) {
    // ваш код...
}
```

то это уже не переопределение, вы пишите полностью свой метод, т.к. он уже как минимум возвращает не объект, а массив... другая сигнатура и т.д. и т.п.

[Тут](https://javarush.ru/groups/posts/1975-kak-ustroen-mekhanizm-pereopredelenija-metodov-) объясняют простым языком про переопределения в Java.

Comment: Мне интересен был момент, могу ли я использовать переопределенный метод clone() в конструкторе и каким образом можно это сделать?

Comment: @Васька, вы этого не озвучили в вопросе. На текущий момент я ответил на ваш вопрос. То, что вы спрашиваете сейчас - тянет на отдельный вопрос.

Comment: @Васька если вы получили ответ на вопрос, отметьте его как решённый

Comment: отметил ) И все-же Вы не подскажете ответ на мой вопрос?

Comment: @Васька если вы хотите использовать переопределенный метод `clone()`, тогда переопределяете его в своем классе и используете в конструкторе.